# Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin

```
/Users/Ren/Desktop/RecylerViewBaseAdapter/build.gradle
Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'
Possible causes:
The project 'RecylerViewBaseAdapter' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766686/using-google-as-a-repository-doesnt-work

Answer (score 140):

The `google()` repo is a shortcut to look in Google's Maven repository for dependencies. It was introduced with [gradle v.4.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#google()).

It requires (currently)

- Gradle v.4
- Android Studio 3.x.
- Gradle plugin for Android 3.x

Try to use in `gradle-wrapper.properties` use:

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

As gradle plugin for Android use:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1'
```

In any case (also with Android Studio 2.3, gradle plugin 2.3.3 and gradle v3.3) you can use the same maven repo using `{ url 'https://maven.google.com'}`. It is the same.

Just use for example:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
 //
}
```

Comment: just a one thing to add, clean project after following above steps

Comment: Just one more add: Always add maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        } before jcenter() !!!

Answer (score 43):

If you use Android studio 2.3.3, then try adding this in your project level gradle

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

this worked for me.

You also can use google() instead but you need Gradle 4.x+, Android Studio 3.x+ , Gradle plugin 3.x+

Comment: doesn't the order matter here?

Answer (score 29):

Just change gradle-wrapper.properties file (below image)

[image: gradle-wrapper.properties]

To this (if your gradle is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1`)

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip // this version or above|
```

For gradle

`com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1`

Use this

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

**UPDATE**

For following gradles

```
//# 1
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1 

//# 2
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0 

//# 3
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1 //or 3.2.0 

//# 4
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2 //or 3.3.0 

//# 5
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0 

//# 6
com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0 

//# 7
com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
```

Use following urls

```
//# 1
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
//# 2
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
//# 3
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip 
//# 4
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
//# 5
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip

//# 6
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip

//# 7
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

**Don't forget adding `google()` in buildscript repositories.**

Answer (score 22):

Looks like you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1

### Solution 1:

Change the distribution URL in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` as follows:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-all.zip`

To locate the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, press `ctrl + shift + N` in Android Studio and type `gradle-wrapper`

Change the dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

## Solution 2:

Use following in your `repositories{...}` blocks instead of `google()`:

```
maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
        // An alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

change your project level gradle file with this,

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

My mistake was fixed after changing the order of elements:

Before:

```
jcenter()
google()
```

After:

```
google()
jcenter()
```

I use the following settings now.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3' // put here an actual version
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0' // put here an actual version

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer may sound ridiculous, but it also fixed my issue after upgraded android studio and gradle!

Answer (score 4):

Accourding to 
[Android gradle plugin release](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)
[image]

So for example if you use plugin version 3.2.1 in:

```
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}
```

You must change the gradle version in

> gradle-wrapper.properties

To

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

**Goodluck**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error due to the lower version on System Gradle than Android Gradle.

System Gradle version lower than Android Gradle version 4.4.
Issue solved after I updated System(Ubuntu machine) Gradle version.

Answer (score 0):

**Please use**

1. `dependencies { classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0' }`
   inside `build.gradle`

   &
2. `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip` inside `gradle-wrapper.properties`

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Gladle v4.7 from this link:
   services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.7-all.zip
2. Extact all content package to path:
   C:\Users\SESSION_NAME.gradle\wrapper\dists
3. Go to Gradle then 'Gradle Settings'

   [image]
4. Choose 'Use local gradle distribution' and enter the path of extracted content

C:\Users\Ahmed.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.7-all\gradle-4.7 & save changes 'apply'

[image]

5. Finaly Rebuild Project in Build menu

Answer (score 0):

Change the distribution URL in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` as follows:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```