# Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint- layout:1.1.0-beta1

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-constraintlayout

This is the error:

```
Error:(23, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-
layout:1.1.0-beta1
Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.3 and sync project
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

When i click in upgrade plugin, nothing happens. I dont know how to fix this. I have tried adding the repository maven google but it doesn't work.

Here is the app code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.google.googleio"
    minSdkVersion 22
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta1'
}
```

Comment: It's the gradle plugin. How does your project build gradle look like?

Comment: set `constraint-layout:1.0.2`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

Comment: setting the constrait-layout works but now i have code errors, i downloaded a template

Comment: add  mavenCentral()  to your repo @ Wolvy

Answer (score 7):

To use ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 beta1 you have to add the google maven repo:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```

More [info here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/05/constraintlayout-110-beta-1-release.html).

Comment: @ThomasVos To use `google()` you need also the plugin 3.3.x and gradle v.4.x. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google/45854844#45854844