# Failed to resolve com.google.android.gms play-services-auth:11.4.0

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-support-library

I am trying to write code for Android FirebaseUI — Auth in my android project but from last two days, I am getting errors in my current code and don't know how to fix it. trying hard but nothing happened in the right way.

here is my build.gradle(project:FriendlyChat)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

here is my build.gradle(Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Displaying images
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: chenge classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

Answer (score 86):

> Failed to resolve com.google.android.gms play-services-auth:11.4.0 .

Add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` to your root level `build.gradle` file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

This maven repo is required starting [from 11.2.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#august_2017_-_version_1120).

You can also use the `google()` shortcut but check the [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google/45854844#45854844) before using it.

Also pay attention since you are using different version. **Use the same version.**

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'
```

**UPDATE**

Firebase Android SDKs and Google Play Services libraries [now have independent version numbers](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html), allowing for more frequent, flexible updates.
Update the google play service gradle plugin version to latest version (at least 3.3.1).

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

and update the libraries to the [latest version](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).

Comment: Might be worth adding that in my case I had to add this under both `allprojects.repositories` and `buildscript.repositories` in build.gradle.

Comment: @josemigallas It is not totally exact. You shoud add it in the `buildscript` block if you have some dependencies in this repo (for example the new android plugin) otherwise it is not useful to add all repos.  In any case it is not related to the question and the 11.4.0

Comment: In my case I already had `mavenCentral()` in the `repositories` section.  I wasn't sure if I should keep that and add the one listed in this post. After running it first with the 2 entries for maven - the build failed. I see the existing one I had, should be replaced with the answer here. Very cool - build is happy now

Comment: Since a few weeks it's not all the same versions anymore. Cannot find the blog post about it anymore, but here's the release notes with latest versions: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android.

Additionally, it should be possible to replace the maven repository definition with a simple google() repository (like naXa mentioned in another answer), but please check my comment on that answer as well.

Comment: @PKuijpers Yes you are right. Now something changed. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 19):

Add `google()` repository to your "build.gradle" file. This gradle method is equivalent to `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

Comment: Better!
However, even though the newer google() repository definition worked perfectly for my projectlast week, today I cannot build my app anymore unless I add the maven definition instead of google()... Not sure if this is a bug from google or me not understanding the difference?
The error says "Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.4]. Required by [...] firebase-analytics:16.0.0"

Comment: @PKuijpers try to ask a new question if you're seeking for help

Answer (score 10):

This error means that google play services 11.4.0 is not installed in your android studio.
To fix this you need to change the version of the dependency to what is installed in your android studio.
For this go to : Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies
Here click on the + sign. Find your desired dependency.You can check its version here.You can also add the dependency to your project from here.

[image: See here]

It is always recommended that you update your google play services SDK tools from SDK manager and use the newest version.

Answer (score 10):

add this in your project level gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer it is ok for me

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem here today and just had to disable gradle offline work option on "File >> Settings  >>  Build, Execution, Deployment  >>  Gradle  >>  Offline work".

Answer (score 3):

Change your top level dependency gradle setting

Open This File --> build.gradle(Project:*****)

and Past This Codes

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Or Just Change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
```

to

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your top level dependency gradle setting

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From Firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

```
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Bottom** position of this line **not** top (below apply plugin: 'com.android.application').

Comment: This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I've turned on gradle offline mode that's why it could not find out cached files for that version play-service or can not resolve. When I turn it on back to online everything is ok now.

> Android Studio ->> File ->> Gradle ->> offline ->> uncheck

Answer (score 2):

Android studio 3.2
Please follow below steps.

1.Invalidate cache and restart option.
   File->Invalidate/Restart

2. delete .gradle folder.

It will sync libs in next launch.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I already had the `google()` repository installed. I was unable to resolve the dependency until I rebooted Android Studio. My guess is it couldn't resolve due to some lingering proxy config from when I had Charles open earlier in the day.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the maven to check the latest version

> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services

and then add maven { URL "https://maven.google.com" } to your root level build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
 repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}


 use this

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'` 

instead of

`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'`
```