# minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, build.gradle

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4] C:\Users\hp elitebook\Desktop\voiceTranslator\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services\11.0.4\AndroidManifest.xml
>       Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.play_services" to force usage

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shaker.voicetranslator"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Comment: Import only the part of the play-services- you need. Nobody needs all of it

Answer (score 3):

You are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

This library in your SDK Manager is resolved with `com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4` (pay attention if you want to use the latest version you have to [add the google maven repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417939/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gms-play-services-auth11-4-0/46418438#46418438)).
This dependency has a **minSdk =14** and you can't use a minSdk=9.

**You have to change**

```
minSdkVersion 9
```

**with**

```
minSdkVersion 14
```

Also, since you will have a dependency with the latest support libraries you have to change the API used to compile. Use:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

Comment: i did it but another problems apear in
C:\Users\hp elitebook\Desktop\voiceTranslator1\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml

and 

C:\Users\hp elitebook\Desktop\voiceTranslator1\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml

Comment: Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.

Comment: @SoufianeLoudghiri It is another error. It depends by api used to compile. Use compileSdkVersion 26

Comment: @SoufianeLoudghiri This is some separate problem. It has nothing to do with your question. There is something wrong with your build.gradle file. You may wish to consider asking a separate question

Comment: but how to develop an app that should run on API level 9?