# Android Studio - Cannot install specific Google Play Services Version

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

Why does Android Studio force a specific version?

[image: Play Services Version 48 Only]

Currently the only option is Version 48 but I require some earlier version that I can't seem to install from this interface. Why is that and how do I install some other version of the Google Play Services? They can't force feed this version to me. Seems silly if I require another version.

Comment: Download that version Offline or use the application gradle for that. Choose lower version in Application gradle while compiling it will give the option to download that google play service version.

Answer (score 0):

> Currently the only option is Version 48 but I require some earlier version that I can't seem to install from this interface

Android Studio provided the latest version in the SDK. Downloading it you were able to use this version and the previous versions.

Now the google play services libraries **are not** in the SDK.
You can donwload the specified version directly from maven.google.com.
Just [add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417939/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gms-play-services-auth11-4-0/46418438#46418438) or the [`google()` shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google/45854844#45854844) in your `build.gradle` script.