# Unable to build ionic project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm trying to build my ionic project, but getting following error (compilation fails in gradle configuration):

> PS C:\Workspace\mobileapp> ionic cordova build android
>   --debug
>
> Running app-scripts build: --platform android --target cordova
>
> [13:05:08]  build dev started ...
>
> [13:05:08]  clean started ...
>
> [13:05:08]  clean finished in 7 ms
>
> [13:05:08]  copy started ...
>
> [13:05:08]  transpile started ...
>
> [13:05:19]  transpile finished in 11.49 s
>
> [13:05:19]  preprocess started ...
>
> [13:05:19]  deeplinks started ...
>
> [13:05:20]  deeplinks finished in 255 ms
>
> [13:05:20] preprocess finished in 256 ms
>
> [13:05:20]  webpack started ...
>
> [13:05:20]  copy finished in 12.27 s
>
> [13:05:37]  webpack finished in 17.47 s
>
> [13:05:37]  sass started ...
>
> [13:05:41]  sass finished in 3.91 s
>
> [13:05:41]  postprocess started ...
>
> [13:05:41]  removed unused font files
>
> [13:05:41]  postprocess finished in 80 ms
>
> [13:05:41]  lint started ...
>
> [13:05:41]  build dev finished in 33.78 s
>
> > cordova build android --debug ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> >     JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151 Starting a Gradle Daemon
> >     (subsequent builds will be faster)
> >     [13:06:05]  lint finished in 23.73 s
>
> :wrapper
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 17s 1 actionable task: 1 executed Subproject Path:
>   CordovaLib The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and
>   is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use
>   Task.doLast(Action) instead.
>
> ```
>     at build_bbib3h28v2rns6xj5u95qezuw.run(C:\Workspace\mobileapp\platforms\android\build.gradle:137)
> ```
>
> The JavaCompile.setDependencyCacheDir() method has been deprecated and
>   is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 4.0.
>
> Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature. The
>   TaskInputs.source(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled
>   to be removed in Gradle 4.0. Please use
>   TaskInputs.file(Object).skipWhenEmpty() instead.
>
> File C:\Users\user.android\repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 20.704 secs FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
>   >     Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.pom
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Workspace/mobileapp/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.pom
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Workspace/mobileapp/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.jar
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
>   >     Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.pom
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Workspace/mobileapp/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.pom
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Workspace/mobileapp/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.jar
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. (node:15112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit
>     code 1 Error output: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
>   >     Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.pom
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Workspace/mobileapp/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.pom
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Workspace/mobileapp/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-auth/11.8.0/play-services-auth-11.8.0.jar
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
>   >     Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.pom
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Workspace/mobileapp/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.pom
>   >          file:/C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.jar
>   >          file:/C:/Workspace/mobileapp/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity/11.8.0/play-services-identity-11.8.0.jar
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>     at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Workspace\mobileapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
>     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:943:16)
>     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:220:5) (node:15112)
>     UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
>     error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
>     without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
>     with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:15112) [DEP0018]
>     DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>     the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>     Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I'm having following version of tools:

1. Ionic: 3.20.0
2. Cordova: 8.0.0
3. Cordova-Android: 6.2.3

Any help would be very grateful.

Comment: Can you show me your project.properties file. You can find it inside platform/Android/

Comment: @SalmanUllah Sure..



target=android-25
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
cordova.system.library.1=com.android.support:support-v4:26.+
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+
cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0

Comment: Comment these two lines and build again also post your output here.

cordova.system.library.3=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0

 cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0

Comment: no success.. this time too long error summary.

C:\Workspace\mobileapp\platforms\android\src\nl\xservices\plugins\GooglePlus.java:16: error: package com.google.android.gms.auth.api does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
                                      ^
C:\Workspace\mobileapp\platforms\android\src\nl\xservices\plugins\GooglePlus.java:17: error: package com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin does not exist
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;

Comment: found a way to resolve the "google-play-services" error- 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417939/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gms-play-services-auth11-4-0