# Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been tryong to add FCM to my android application for almost 48 hours now. I am keep on failing with these two errors on Android Studio. I have tried all the solutions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417939/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gms-play-services-auth11-4-0). Still I couldn't fix it.

I want firebase cloud messaging to be integrated in my app. So I did the followings.

- Created an app in the firebase console
- Included the .json config file
- Added the SDK
- `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'`
       (In the app level gradle)
- `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` (In the app level gradle file last
  line)
- `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`
  (In the project level gradle)
- Added the repository
  `google()` (In the project level gradle)

I have tried syncing many times and I keep on getting the error

> Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks Open File
>
> Failed to resolve: play-services-basement Open File

On a side note, I am using the gradle plugin 3.1.3

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

Can someone please give me a hand here please.

Comment: It would be easier if you post the whole build.gradle file so others could try and copy-paste it on their side and see the errors themselves.

Comment: Could you try adding the google() repository as the first option in your dependencies blocks?

Comment: @ArthurThompson it worked. May I kbow the reason for this please?

Comment: I believe there was an issue with the dependencies pushed/synced to jcenter and others. This will likely be resolved in a future push but for now using the google() repo first will allow all Firebase dependencies to resolve correctly.

Comment: Alright. I can accept an answer or can delete the post. But I think it should stay in SO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`jcenter()` sometimes act as a mirror repository for some Google dependencies. During Gradle building process, it looks for dependencies in the first entry listed in your `repositories {...}` block. So if this repository is broken or something bad occurs with any dependency the process will fail.

Here there is a recommended order for repository list

```
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
```

Comment: late but a better answer. This explains why the order matters in this case.

Answer (score 81):

In `gradle (project)`,
just change the position of `google()` before `jcenter()`,
and the error is gone.

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Could you explain the reason? Just curiosity.

Comment: jcenter() need to be the last repositories, seem that jcenter() are using some of the repositories in google(). Putting jcenter() first will cause some repositories fail to load

Answer (score 11):

Put google() repository at the very first line of dependencies. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

Add in your app.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

and upgrade your dependencies version.

Answer (score 0):

I had this occurring due to outdated build tools version.  Updating from 28.0.2 to 28.0.3 resolved it.

```
buildToolsVersion '28.0.2'
```

to:

```
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
```

in build.gradle file.