# Android gradle dependencies conflicts and duplicate value for resource

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Following are gradle dependencies in my app

```
ext {
supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'
playServicesVersion = '16.0.0'
firebaseVersion = '16.0.4'
}
 dependencies {

implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation project(':pageIndicator')
implementation('io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.+') {
    exclude module: 'answers-shim'
}
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'

//Support library
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibraryVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibraryVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${supportLibraryVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:${supportLibraryVersion}"
implementation "com.android.support:exifinterface:${supportLibraryVersion}"
//Support library

//play services
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${playServicesVersion}"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.5"
//play services

implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:7.0.0'
implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'

//firebase
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.0"
//firebase

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.7.5'
implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.1.4'
implementation 'com.ncapdevi:frag-nav:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
implementation 'com.evernote:android-job:1.1.11'
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
implementation 'com.toptoche.searchablespinner:searchablespinnerlibrary:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.bigbangbutton:editcodeview:1.0.5'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.30.0'
implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.koushikdutta.async:androidasync:2.+'
implementation 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.7'
implementation 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

}

I am getting following error message while making build
**Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.0.**

Tried running following command to see dependency tree

```
gradle dependencies --configuration compile
```

Following is output of command

```
\--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0
 +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0
 |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1
 |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
 |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0
 |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
 |    |         |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0
 |    |         |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.0
 |    |         |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
 |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0
 |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
 |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
 |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
 |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
 |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
 |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0
 |    |         |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
 |    |         |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
 |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0
 |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
 |    |              +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0 (*)
 |    |              \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0 (*)
 |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.4] -> 15.0.4
 |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1
 |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
 |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.0.0] -> 16.0.0
 |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:15.0.1
 |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1,16.0.0) -> 15.0.1 (*)
 |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
 |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.4] -> 15.0.4
 |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 (*)
 |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1
 |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
 |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0
 |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
 |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
 |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:16.0.0
 |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
 |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-stats:15.0.1 (*)
 |    |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1 (*)
 |    |         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
 |    |         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:16.0.0
 |    |              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1
 |    |              |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
 |    |              |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:[15.0.1] -> 15.0.1 (*)
 |    |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
 |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
 \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:16.0.0
      +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
      +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:[15.0.4] -> 15.0.4
      +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:[16.0.0] -> 16.0.0 (*)
      +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:[16.0.0] -> 16.0.0 (*)
      +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:16.0.0 (*)
      \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector:16.0.0
           \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15.0.1 (*)
```

(*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously)

Not getting where exactly conflict is and how to solve it?

solved this by updating main gradle file as below

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/piasy/maven"
    }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Now getting following issue

error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/fontStyle' with config ''.
app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1421: error: resource previously defined here.

Comment: I tried to resolve this issue to... 3 days no answers

Comment: What is you com.google.gms:google-services version in app (project level) 
build.gradle?

Comment: You provided libraries list from dependencies. But what's the version of the google-services plugin?

Comment: using 16.0.0 version

Answer (score 0):

looks like

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics
```

Using com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1

Please update firebase. Try use

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:+
```

The next step is force configuration:

```
android{
    configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:${playServicesVersion}"
    }
}
```

Please check your build gradle version and update  `com.android.tools.build:gradle`

Comment: getting error Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:16.0.0"

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940565/failed-to-resolve-play-services-tasks

Comment: getting error merged.dir\values\values.xml:621: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/fontStyle' with config ''.

Comment: update android build tools to 28.0.3 and android compile version to 28

Comment: still getting issue

Answer (score 0):

updated main gradle file solved this conflict updated com.android.tools.build:gradle and 
com.google.gms:google-services versions

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
 }

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/piasy/maven"
    }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    google()
}
 }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```