# Failed to resolve: play-services-base-license

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, jcenter

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

I am using the above gradle to build the project. But when  I try to build the project I am getting the following error.
Error : Failed to resolve: play-services-base-license

I tried changing the order of repositries like below :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
```

When I do this I am getting following error.
Error: Could not find intellij-core.jar (com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.0.1/intellij-core-26.0.1.jar

Is there any way I can solve this problem? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this `repositories {
    google()
jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }

}`

Comment: Even with that change I am getting :Failed to resolve: play-services-base-license

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940565/failed-to-resolve-play-services-tasks

Comment: I already saw that post and tried. It did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Firstly in **project** build.gradle file, add:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
           google()
           maven { 
             url "https://maven.google.com" 
           }  
          jcenter()     
        }
    }
```

Then in **module** build.gradle file,add:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
```