# Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks-license (putting google() before jcenter() doesn't work)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Whenever I try to run my app I got the following gradle error:

> Failed to resolve: play-services-tasks-license

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50940565/failed-to-resolve-play-services-tasks) question, I have tried every possible solution, but none of them worked.

**If I put google() to the first row of the dependencies, the error still appears.**

Please help if you can.

**My app-level build.gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        applicationId 'com.myapppackage.app'
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 77
        versionName '1.5.53'
        multiDexEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'io.appflate.restmock.android.RESTMockTestRunner'
    }
}


repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0' 

    implementation files('libs/youtube.jar')

}
```

**My project-level gradle file:**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change your project-level `build.gradle` file like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And remove this

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

and this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
```

from your app `build.gradle` file

> PS: You can remove `implementation files('libs/youtube.jar')` too because you are already importing the lib with this line: `implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')`