# How to get Current Location in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am using android studio version 3.3.1 and working on google map code for getting the current location. When I am adding permission in gradle.build file then I have got an error.

This file I am adding:
......................................................................

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.1.0'
```

Got these error while I syn the gradle:

> ERROR: Failed to resolve:
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.1.0
>
> Install Repository and sync project
>
> Show in Project Structure dialog
>
> Affected Modules: app

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
Affected Modules: app

....................................................................

When I click the error of "Install Repository and sync project" the got could not find dependencies.

Comment: Use this  `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"`

Comment: did you add `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }` in your root-level gradle file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to resolve com.google.android.gms play-services-auth:11.4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417939/failed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gms-play-services-auth11-4-0)

Answer (score 2):

The latest version for that dependency is 16.0.0. You're using 16.1.0 which doesn't exist for the location services package.

> Google Location and Activity Recognition  com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0

Answer (score 0):

There is 16.0.1, you can either use 16.0.0 or upgrade to the latest version of now (17.0.0)
Complete list of releases are available [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-location)