# Difference between google() and maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there any difference between google() and maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } in build.gradle file and if there is any, what is it?

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        // OR
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: maven.google for android studio 2.3 and below versions.
google()  for android studio 3.0.0 and above. ( it's the same fuctionality)

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45854844/1370087) for more details.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The `google()` repository is a shortcut to Google's maven repository. It was introduced in Gradle 4.x+. The actual repository URL used is `"https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/" as specified [here.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#google()) https://maven.google.com actually points to the same repository.

However, if you are planning to use the `google()` shortcut, you need Gradle 4.x+, Android Studio 3.x+ and Gradle plugin for Android 3.x+.

Comment: More details here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#mavenGoogleRepo

Comment: Note @Sergio answer for URL, docs not updated still (or documented link is not for web access ...)

Answer (score 11):

Small correction to the answer above. 
If you try to go to https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/ it gives you a 404.
The correct url to google maven repository is:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html
or just 
https://maven.google.com

Here you can check all the supported libraries and the latest versions.

Comment: I think url may be changed beetwen gradle versions so this is the main purpose of shortcut

Comment: This should have been posted as a comment to Jayson's answer.

Comment: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html is also 404 now

Comment: all these links are 404 now...

Comment: The links are working.

Answer (score 1):

When using gradle, you can mention multiple repositories which the build tool (gradle) uses to resolve dependencies mentioned in your project.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    google()
}
```

In the above scenario, you're mentioning 3 repositories which gradle can use to resolve dependencies—all of which are Maven repositories.

**1. jcenter()**

- Means the [JCenter Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/repos/jcenter) repository.
- This is a shortcut available in later versions of gradle

**2. { url 'https://maven.google.com' }**

- This means you are referring a Maven repo hosted at the URL which can be used by gradle to resolve the dependencies.
- If you want, you can actually enter the URL for JCenter and this would be the same as mentioning `jcenter()` in the gradle file.

**3. google()**

- This means the Google Maven repository
- Similar to the notation `maven()`, this can be used in later versions of gradle only