# Gradle build tool cannot find play-services-tasks.aar? Why?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Today suddenly, I got an error when I tried to run my app in Android studio.

It is:

```
Error: Could not find play-services-tasks.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/15.0.1/play-services-tasks-15.0.1.aar
```

[image: gradle_build_error]

I didn't change anything in the gradle file but it appeared suddenly. My previous build executed successfully some minutes ago.

Why it can't find  `play-services-tasks.aar` which is the part of  **com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1**

**Steps taken:**

I checked whether I included all repositories in the gradle files and all are correct so far.

Why does this error occur all of a sudden?

I also copied this link https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/15.0.1/play-services-tasks-15.0.1.aar into the browser but it's working fine, that is, I got "File Download" dialog.

---

**My Gradle Files**

- App level

  ```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 26
      buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "mekanic24assistantapplication.heba.mekanic24.com.mekanic24assistantapplication"
          minSdkVersion 14
          targetSdkVersion 26
          versionCode 13
          versionName "2.1"
          testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
          multiDexEnabled true
      }
      buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
      }


      dexOptions {
          incremental true
          javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
      }

  //    err Android Gradle Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/license.txt

      configurations.all {

          resolutionStrategy {
              force 'com.android.support:support-v4:26+'
              force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26+'


          }

      }


      packagingOptions {
          exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
          exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
          exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
          exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
          exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
          exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
          exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
          exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
          exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
          exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
      }

  }

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
          exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
      })
      //   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.3.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:26+'
      compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26+'
      compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26+'
      compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
      androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26+'
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      //   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.3.1'
      compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
      //  compile 'com.android.support:design:26.3.1'
      compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
      compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'
      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
      compile 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
      compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
      compile 'android.lib.recaptcha:reCAPTCHA:2.0.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:15.0.1'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'

      compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.38'
      compile files('libs/mail.jar')
      compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
      compile files('libs/activation.jar')
      compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
      annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
      compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.1.0'
      compile 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.3'
      compile 'com.github.stfalcon:smsverifycatcher:0.3.1'
      compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
      //TODO:  Apache 2.0 license https://github.com/ACRA/acra
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
      compile 'com.github.luongvo:GmailBackground:2.0.2'

  }
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  ```
- Project Level

  ```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
      maven {
          url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools"
      }

      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
      google()

  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'

      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
  }
  }

  allprojects {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
      maven {
          url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools"
      }

      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
      google()

  }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
  ```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After doing the following changes the error disappeared:

1. Removed `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` from repositories in app build.gradle.
2. Added `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` as **first entry** in **allprojects/repositories** in top level build.gradle
3. Changed all play-services and firebase dependencies to the latest versions
4. Changed version of google-services plugin to `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Comment: seems crazy, but this worked for me too... 1 or 2 did the job (having problems with another google dep)

Comment: I'm working on an ionic application (using cordova), so I don't know where this (allprojects/repositories) folder would be. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: @bvx89 Sorry, I don't know how ionic solves dependencies. In my solution I assume that Gradle resolves repository urls sequentially top to bottom. This would mean, that Gradle looks first in Google's maven repository. But that's just my assumption. Try to change your settings to have the link to Google's maven repo first. Hope this helps.

Comment: @bvx89You can open the platform folder via android studio. There you see the gradle files under gradle scripts. Somehow the issue was solved for me by rearranging the repositorie ordering in all sub gradle files as described here. After this, normal cordova build is working again.

Comment: @IvanRigamonti .. Worked for me. I just executed steps 1 & 2 and it worked as a charm. Thank you very much . You saved my time

Comment: Actually the weird thing is, it did not work for me the first couple of times. Then after some resets and retries it suddenly works again (even though, some of the edited files are reset by cordova again all the time). Also, I don't need to adjust any versions. Strange issue.

Comment: @IvanRigamonti  .. Will you please explain how this reordering method solved this issue? Any technical explanations are there ?

Comment: @Frank, I found out what Ivan Rigamonti meant and did steps 1 & 2. It worked right away. I see that SimbaClaws is suggesting rearranging the repositories as a fix, but I haven't tried it myself. I think the best option is to just do the hack until bintray is fixed, and revert back afterwards.

Comment: @LordCommander I assume that Gradle loads repositories according to the sequence in the build.gradle file. Thus, in my case after the described change it looks first for dependencies in Google's maven repo and then at jcenter() and last at google():
'allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}'
I can only guess that one of the two other repos had not yet updated dependencies.

Comment: [`google()` is the official way to add that maven repo as of Gradle version 4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46467561/2308683)

Comment: @IvanRigamonti Does the order not matter for Gradle plugin 2.x+..Because this error is new to me

Comment: This worked. But this is not at all good. Something such simple changes and you need to bang your head to get it working.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.. Just moving `google()` line to the top magically worked!!

Comment: Thanks @IvanRigamonti : you save me :)

Answer (score 27):

The fix is to put google url above jcenter() in your repository list in gradle.

Here's the issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80362794

Answer (score 8):

in my case:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

solves my problems

- in my old configuration was only "jcenter()"
- first line jcenter(), second line google() doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

For my case I removed `mavenCentral()` from **app gradle** repositores and moved `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` to the first positionin in **project gradle** as Ivan Rigamonti suggested above. No Firebase dependecies update needed.

(this should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same issue today. It was working fine until now. Maybe it's a temporary Google servers issue.

The solution that works for me is using an older version of google-play-services:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
```

Comment: If I change version code for just maps then I have to change version code in all google play services ... If not then I will led to version conflict

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

Is my case, it works!

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that google changed the naming conventions of the packages on the server side?

I'm experiencing the same sort of issue with a different play services package just now.

Namely play-services-basement.aar...

I'm thinking that

```
Could not find play-services-tasks.aar
```

Means it's looking for the file named as play-services-tasks.aar

While on the server this file is called:

```
play-services-tasks-15.0.1.aar
```

I'm thinking this is either a gradle issue where files aren't named correctly or a server side issue where files aren't named correctly.

Please correct me if I'm mistaken here.

EDIT: this issue should be reported to jcenter.bintray.com since they are the ones being at fault here at their server side. Switching to the Maven repository mentioned by Ivan Rigamonti could be a solution but I'm uncertain how ionic apps deal with switching repositories.

EDIT2: Switching to the maven repository does indeed work for ionic. All I had to do for ionic was to alter build.gradle by putting jcenter() underneath maven() inside of the buildscript repositories and allprojects repositories.

Comment: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-tasks/15.0.1/play-services-tasks-15.0.1.aar     

The link is working in broswer

Comment: yes I realised the link is working but I also see that the file named in gradle is different then the one in the url, which could be why it's comming up with this issue? Basically the version isn't appended to the end of the file in gradle...

Comment: I understand.. How can I change the filename in gradle?

Comment: I am uncertain myself what to do at this point. I'm thinking it's something that has to be fixed from google's end? I'm just hypothesizing here, I'm not really contributing an actual solution but rather extend the question based on what I think is happening.

Based on how many people are viewing this topic I'm guessing more people are having this problem right now.

Comment: yes but for a different package, play-services-basement.aar
Same symptoms though, the url works but the error remains.

Comment: I am very sad. I have to release this app before May 31st.. So it need to be fixed soon

Comment: I am thinking that lot of developers experiencing this issue

Comment: I think there are some problems with the repository (server side) since this same error has been reported multiple times

Answer (score 0):

if you Guys Getting Error Like **build.gradle error , Failed to resolve: common** like this [build.gradle error , Failed to resolve: common](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50565776/8416317)

then put below line in **allprojects** scope in repositories scope in **Project build.gradle**

line :

```
 maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        google()
```

example

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
```