# Failed to resolve: play-services-flags

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Today, Android Studio stopped to sync properly due to configuration issues.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ‘:app:providerRepositoryDebugCompileClasspath’.
>    Could not find firebase-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2).
>    Searched in the following locations:
>        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-analytics-impl/15.0.2/firebase-analytics-impl-15.0.2.aar
>   Could not find play-services-flags.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1).
>    Searched in the following locations:
>        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-flags/15.0.1/play-services-flags-15.0.1.aar

These two files exist, and I can download them through web browser.

I have fixed first issue by updating firebase core to 16.0.0.
(Failed to resolve: firebase-analytics-impl), but I cannot fix the 2nd one.

What's wrong with Android Studio?
Yesterday it worked well.

Please don't suggest to add flags library from gms. I tried that already.

Comment: Please explain why you gave me negative points. If you don't want, please skip this question.

Comment: set classpath `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Comment: I have the same issue with cordova. Suddenly it is not working anymore.

Comment: Got the same issue, too. In my case play-services-places-placereport and play-services-basement cannot be fetched.

Comment: To elaborate on my similar issues: We use cordova to create our app. Today I set up a clean workspace. Did cordova add android and build and there I get the same error. When I open the project with android studio, I see it there, too. Tried so far to play around with the library versions, but nothing helps.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Unfortunately, setting to 4.0.1 didn't work either.

Comment: [Gustav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2273583/gustav) would like to add: They should not down vote you - I am having the same issue. (copied from a now deleted answer (that wasn’t an answer))

Comment: Same thing here, literally nothing helps, even clean reinstall of AS and all libraries

Comment: Please look at my answer for question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why/50564970#50564970.

Comment: @IvanRigamonti You are right, 2nd thing did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Fixed by changing order of repos in PROJECT build.grade:

Instead of

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

put

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I think someone suggested this but I don't see his answer anymore.

Very strange issue.

Comment: It worked for me. Try to play around with repos, something weird happened there.

Comment: In my case everything is even worse: I have 
Failed to resolve: firebase-messaging
Failed to resolve: support-core-ui
Failed to resolve: fabric
So essentially nothing really works, and I've tried everything: moving up and down repositories, updating play services and etc

But thanks for the advice!

Comment: @GeorgySavatkov Did you update your dependencies to the latest versions? By doing that, I fixed Failed to resolve: firebase-analytics-impl issue. Also, did you update classpath to 4.0.1 ?

Comment: Oh, I just realised that `jcenter` has to be moved down in `allprojects` section. Your solution does work, thank you!

It's still freaking ridiculous, I've spent like 4 hours figuring this out!

Comment: @GeorgySavatkov I am glad you fixed it. 
I spent too many time on this, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its really helps. +1

Comment: Yeah this works. @vanste25 You are right, someone suggested this but it not traceable now. Also, `google()` is required to be placed on top of all as suggested by @Denis in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50564890/4632372) answer.

Answer (score 10):

They were changing and deleting old libraries, I guess.

I finally managed to get it working, by changing the order of repositories in project build.gradle:

```
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
            }
            jcenter()
        }
    }
```

jcenter should be the last.

Comment: try updating everything to last version, also update classpath to 4.0.1, as one other comment decribes, and check that jcenter is always the last

Comment: Thank you. I tried various solutions, but this easy fix with changing a few lines helped me to finally solve the issue. I am using Ionic with Android version 6.4.0.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

in **project `build.gradle`**

in dependencies tag

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

and import repositories like below

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

in **app build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

Now the confusing part is why use `google()` not

```
maven { url "https://maven.google.com"  }
```

because `google()` is its replacement in android studio 3+

Also make sure to use correct version of firebase sdk from [Firebase SDK documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)