# Jenkins unable to find com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I'm trying to build my project in a new Jenkins job where I am updating the dependencies to Android API-27. Nevertheless, I'm always getting the folowing error:

> :smartconnectapilibrary:compileDebugAidl
>   Putting task artifact state for task ':smartconnectapilibrary:compileDebugAidl' into context took 0.0 secs.
>   Creating new cache for metadata-2.23/artifact-at-url, path /Users/jenkins/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.23/artifact-at-url.bin, access org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess@100205c4
>   Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.pom]
>   Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.jar]
>   :smartconnectapilibrary:compileDebugAidl FAILED
>   :smartconnectapilibrary:compileDebugAidl (Thread[Task worker for ':' Thread 4,5,main]) completed. Took 0.612 secs.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

I have updated both entries to `compileSdkVersion 27` and `buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'` everywhere, and added `google()` in the `repositories` section.

I have also read, that maybe Jenkins ignores the `google()` repository, so it never finds the dependency `com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1`

Also, this is a composite project (one main module, and two library modules) each with their own gradle files. In each of them, I already have `google()` before `jcenter()` but still I have this issue and I think it may be in the way of how Gradle stacks the gradle files.

Does somebody know a solution?

**UPDATE**

I see that for some reason, Gradle is looking for`com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1` in `/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/extras/` **instead of** `/jenkins/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/`

> - What went wrong:
>     Could not resolve all files for configuration ':fisherpriceapilibrary:debugCompileClasspath'.
>     Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.pom
>       file:/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.jar
>       file:/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.pom
>       file:/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.jar
>       file:/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.pom
>       file:/Users/jenkins/Library/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.jar
>     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.pom
>       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/27.1.1/support-v4-27.1.1.jar
>     Required by:
>       project :smartconnectapilibrary > project :someapilibrary

Comment: Would you please provide the `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Are you add this `maven {
                url "https://maven.google.com"
            }` on all project repositories.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed yes, I have added `google()` which is the same than `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`... actually I have tried both. This is not only one `build.gradle` file, they are multiple ones, because this is a composite project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sound a bit funny, but this has been a problem with Jenkins and Android projects in the past.

For some strange reasons, you have to prioritize the repositories to look into in your build.gradle. I say, this is not a great way of fixing this, but this will work for sure. I just ran into the same issue two days back.

Please look here for the answer: [Failed to resolve: play-services-flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50563297/failed-to-resolve-play-services-flags)

Comment: Upon investigation, I found this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80362794

Comment: @VighneshPal thank you for your answer. I'm pretty much sure that my issue is quite related to this. Anyway, this is a composite project (one main module, and two library modules) each with their own gradle files. In each of them, I already have `google()` before `jcenter()` but still I have this issue and i think it my be in the way of how these gradles stack each other. I will update the question.

Comment: Finally, the issue was that I needed to place the google() above the jcenter() repository for each subproject. Subprojects are not showing the Gradle files of the root directory in Android Studio, so I haven't figured out about it on a first instance.