# react native app build failing for react-native firebase

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, build

we have "react-native-firebase": "4.2.0", after installing npm modules and try to run the app then we are getting this issue

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find firebase-auth.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-auth/15.1.0/firebase-auth-15.1.0.aar
  >   Could not find firebase-analytics-impl.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:15.0.2).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-analytics-impl/15.0.2/firebase-analytics-impl-15.0.2.aar
  >   Could not find firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:15.0.1).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/15.0.1/firebase-common-15.0.1.aar
  >   Could not find firebase-common.aar (com.google.firebase:firebase-common:15.0.1).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/firebase/firebase-common/15.0.1/firebase-common-15.0.1.aar
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: do you have `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'` in your *android/app/build.gradle* file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle build tool cannot find play-services-tasks.aar? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

> react-native link react-native-firebase ?

Comment: remove android and ios folders from the project and run `react-native eject & react-native link react-native-firebase` , see if it helps

Comment: please post *questions* as *comments* and not as *answers*

Comment: @Cherniv i know, but i do not have enough points, so i cannot comment direct.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the question, but there is no specific google firebase configuration for react-native, so you need to log in to your project inside https://console.firebase.google.com/, access your project and go in web configurations and implement in your code.

ex:

```js
componentWillMount() {
        firebase.initializeApp({
            apiKey: "YOURAPIKEY",
            authDomain: "",
            databaseURL: "",
            projectId: "",
            storageBucket: "",
            messagingSenderId: "YOURKEY"
        });
```

Cheers,