# failed to resolve : firebase-analytics failed to resolve:play-service-base

Tags: java, android, firebase, gradle

Help me to solve those errors in my gradle.

Errors:

> Warning:Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has
>   been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation' and 'androidTestApi'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Warning:Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation' and 'api'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For
>   more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Warning:Configuration 'androidTestApi' is obsolete and has been
>   replaced with 'androidTestImplementation'. It will be removed at the
>   end of 2018. For more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Warning:Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced
>   with 'testImplementation' and 'testApi'. It will be removed at the end
>   of 2018. For more information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Warning:Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'testImplementation'. It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more
>   information see:
>   http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: firebase-analytics Open
>   File
>
> Error:Failed to resolve: play-services-base Open
>   File

Those error and warning found in my gradle.

These error appeared recently, Previous there was no problem.

This is my app gradle:-

```
       'apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.alagappan.vivo"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner
        "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
      release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),      'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
         }
      compileOptions {
      targetCompatibility 1.8
      sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
   }

      buildscript {
      repositories {
      jcenter()
    }
      dependencies {
         classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.5.1'
     }
   }

dependencies {
   androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-     core:2.2.2', {
     exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12' 
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
  compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
  compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
  compile 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.9'
 }' 



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is application side gradle:-

```
'// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      google()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
      // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
      // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

buildscript {
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // google-services     plugin 
  }
}
allprojects {
  repositories {
      jcenter()
      google()
  } 
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}'
```

Thanking You in advance friends

Comment: Now i got correct solution thank you @Floern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove:

```
 compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.0'
```

since it is deprecated. 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/quickstart.html

Change the top level gradle file to this:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Change:

- `compile` to `implementation`
- `androidTestCompile` and `androidTestApi` to `androidTestImplementation`
- `testCompile` and `testApi` to `testImplementation`

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration

Comment: I got corrected the warnings but not error

Comment: Sure and thanking you @Peter_Haddad

Comment: The key for me was making sure google() was listed first (ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why)

Comment: yes google() is listed first in the answer @LordParsley

Comment: Yip @PeterHaddad just drawing attention to it because I didn't think it'd be important at first but mine was listed second and not working :-)