# Android gradle issue 'Failed to resolve: support-core-ui'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

This is all I have as my project's dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
api "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1"
api "com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:15.0.1"
implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.0'
```

}

And after trying to sync my android's gradle I get:

> Failed to resolve: support-core-ui

I know that the support-core-ui is included inside support-v4 but I can't think of any solution, I'd be thankful if anyone had any idea about this

Comment: Have you tried File->Settings->Gradle and uncheking "Offline work" ?

Comment: @milano95a Yeah, Its not checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle build tool cannot find play-services-tasks.aar? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why)

Comment: @MohammadReza Did you manage to find solution?

Comment: @Jovan Yes, Apparently something was wrong with jcenter and stuff

Answer (score 3):

Placing the `google()` repo before the `jcenter()` repo in the Project build.gradle fixed the issue.

Based on: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80362794

Comment: Hmm useful, not sure how does it possible

Answer (score 0):

Add below [support-core-ui](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages) to your dependencies and try again:

```
com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
```

Just for your information now, *parts of support-core-ui, support-core-utils, and support-compat into smaller libraries*.

Check here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions