# error: Failed to resolve: support-core-ui

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

**1) Doesn't work:**

*First Click 'Sync' gradle*

*Then clean and rebuild the application*

*And invalidate and restart*

**2) Have:**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenLocal()
        google()
    }
}
```

**3) Tried to implement library:**

```
com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1
```

**Also, sometime i get this error**:

> Could not find support-core-ui.jar
>   (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1).
>       Searched in the following locations:
>           https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core-ui/27.1.1/support-core-ui-27.1.1.jar
>
> ```
> Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
> Open Android SDK Manager
> ```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681155/android-studio-error-you-must-install-the-android-support-repository-though-th

Comment: I may be stating the obvious here but have you checked that the Android Support Repository is installed in the Android SDK Manager?

Comment: @Sander certainly

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/51734957/1204249