# Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.1.2)

Tags: android, gradle, build

I just got into work this morning and my build just stopped working, showing the error below:

```
Could not find baseLibrary.jar (com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.1.2).
Searched in the following locations: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/databinding/baseLibrary/3.1.2/baseLibrary-3.1.2.jar
```

I already updated everything in Android Studio (SDK, NDK, Gradle plugin, etc), already tried adding the following lines suggested in another question:

```
implementation 'com.android.databinding:library:3.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.databinding:adapters:3.2.1'
```

Nothing of that works, still having the same problem. 
Any body has any idea of what is causing this?

EDIT: It may look like this is a duplicate of [Gradle build tool cannot find play-services-tasks.aar? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why)
but the accepted answer did not help me, and it's a different problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle build tool cannot find play-services-tasks.aar? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why)

Comment: It may look like it, but the problem is different and the accepted answer did not help me.