# cannot find lint-checks.jar

Tags: android, lint

I've downloaded a new android project and for some reason I get this error when I am trying to build the app:

```
Could not find lint-checks.jar (com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.1). Searched in the following locations: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/lint/lint-checks/26.0.1/lint-checks-26.0.1.jar
```

Weirdly, when I go to that url I can download the jar, so i'm really unsure why Android studio is complaining. I've downloaded the latest version - 3.1.2.

I've also tried disabling lint but no luck with removing the error!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.1'
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.17.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.3.3"
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven" }
        flatDir {
            dirs '../aars'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle build tool cannot find play-services-tasks.aar? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why)

Comment: To be precise, swap `jcenter()` and `google()` in the `buildscript { repositories { .. } }` block.

Comment: @Floern this worked!!! THANKYOU. Why does this work? :S

Answer (score 1):

I also started getting this issue this morning.  I had not updated anything, not really sure what changed over the weekend.

I managed to fix the issue by updating my **buildToolsVersion** from **26.0.2** to **27.0.3**, which also required me to update my **Gradle version** from **4.3** to **4.4** and my **Gradle Plug-in** from **3.0.1** to **3.1.2**.

This was before I saw the solution provided by Floern, which also works.  Not sure why though and i figured it's always better to stay up to date with the latest versions of Gradle.

Comment: Updating the versions of build tools, Gradle and Gradle plug-in did not work for me. Putting google() first in the repositories block was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to add "com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.0.1" to your gradle dependencies

Comment: didn't work =(. I've added my gradle file to the post. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Unity people, Wrong password for your "project key" (the second one)

this might seems unrelated to the OP's question but is the first google result for people having similar exception in Unity and their gradle build that says `Could not load custom lint`
if you enter wrong password for the first one, the exception clearly states wrong password but the second one the "project key" has this diabolical exception that takes you to these places with similar but unrelated exceptions.