# Failed to resolve: support-core-ui

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

This is all I have as my project's repositories:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
}
```

This is all I have as my project's dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:16.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1"
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle build tool cannot find play-services-tasks.aar? Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why)

Comment: 1) NineOldAndroids is deprecated. 2) Dagger and JavaX have their own Gradle targets. Don't use JAR files unless absolutely necessary. 3) Do not use `play-services:12.0.1` - Use only Google services you actually *need* (such as ads and appinvites). Also, each of those Google versions need to match exactly 4) GCM is being replaced by Firebase FCM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        jcenter()
    }
```

Answer (score 15):

I solved this issue by changing

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

into

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

in project level build.gradle file, i.e. first writing google().