# Failed to resolve: common and Failed to resolve: support-core-ui after update android studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

So after update android studio and gradle getting so many error but now I am stuck on below error msg . 
[image]

Now below is my gradle file :-

[image]

Now if I try to change buildToolsVersion 27.0.3 to 27.1.1 then it shows below error :-

[image]

**Showing this error as well**

> - What went wrong: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
>   > Could not find support-core-ui.aar (com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.1.1).   Searched in the
>   >     following locations:
>   >       https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-core-ui/27.1.1/support-core-ui-27.1.1.aar

So I tried so many thing to resolve and Stackover flow question but not resolve my problem.

[Failed to resolve: support-core-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566524/failed-to-resolve-support-core-ui)

[image]

Comment: The latest version of build tool is 27.0.3 https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools

Comment: Did you tried after invalidating cache by deleting .gradle/caches file and resync?

Comment: You need to check for the conflicted libraries with `gradlew app:dependencies`, please check my previous answer on the same problems for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50183287/all-the-libraries-must-use-the-same-versions/50192030#50192030

Comment: @E.Abdel i tried both thing which mentioned above but still on a same page thanks for taking time for me

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך I am trying what u suggest let u know when something good happened

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך is right, try in a first time to resolve conflicts by overriding each library showed in the hint (adding it to dependencies) with the same version number of appcompat lib

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך dnt understand where i miss the trick still facing same issue ... but thanks for help and trying to digging more for resolve issue