# Gradle is not downloading .aar dependency properly (no files just manifest.mf)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aar, gradle-dependencies

When I was not able to resolve some of the classes located in external dependency I debugged and found that gradle is some how not downloading jars properly. I have checked on my peer computer that this `play-services-tasks-15.0.1.aar` is around 127 KB. 
Also there are no files in the jar downloaded by gradle other than `MANIFEST.MF` in `META-INF` folder.

*NOTE: This `play-services-tasks` dependency is itself coming from `firebase-core` dependency*

Here are some of the screenshot of what I just described:

(Less than 1 KB in size)
[image]

And (No classes in jar file)

[image]

**I have also tried to delete `play-services-tasks-15.0.1.aar` file and rebuild/clean/invalidate caches, but still haven't found any luck. Please tell me how to resolve this issue?**

Thank you for answers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try setting transitive property for your aar like this

```
    compile('play-services-tasks-15.0.1@aar') { 
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Comment: this dependency is coming from another dependency i.e. `com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1`

Comment: And applying transitive property on `firebase-core` dependency isn't working

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil this might fix your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562212/gradle-build-tool-cannot-find-play-services-tasks-aar-why