# Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[16.0.0]

Tags: android, cordova, firebase

I use [FCM plugin](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) in my cordova app. I get the following error after executing `cordova build android` in my command prompt.

```
Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:[16.0.0].
     Versions that do not match:
         11.0.4
         11.0.2
         11.0.1
         11.0.0
         10.2.6
         + 14 more
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/ZenHelp/ZenHelp2017/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/ZenHelp/ZenHelp2017/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/
         file:/D:/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/
         file:/D:/ZenHelp/ZenHelp2017/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/ZenHelp/ZenHelp2017/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/firebase/firebase-iid/
     Required by:
         project : > com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0
   > Could not find any version that matches com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.1].
     Versions that do not match:
         11.0.4
         11.0.2
         11.0.1
         11.0.0
         10.2.6
         + 17 more
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/D:/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/ZenHelp/ZenHelp2017/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/ZenHelp/ZenHelp2017/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/
         file:/D:/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/
         file:/D:/ZenHelp/ZenHelp2017/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/D:/ZenHelp/ZenHelp2017/platforms/android/sdk-manager/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/
     Required by:
         project : > com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:15.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
(node:2404) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

I checked `ANDROID_HOME` path and its correct. I also updated my android sdk tools where my `Google Play Services` is updated to version `49` and `Google repository` to version `58`. I tried with `cordova clean android` also.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

open your `build.gradle` located at `platforms/android`

and find

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral();
    jcenter()
 }
}
```

then replace it with

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      maven {
         url "https://maven.google.com"
      }
   }
}
```

this worked for me

Comment: I faced the same issue. This answer resolved it. Can you please explain why we have to update this particular file? Also, now when I take an android build for the app, it does not get installed. Unfortunately, 'APPNAME' has stopped error is being shown.

Comment: more explanation is found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46467800/4183947

Answer (score 0):

I followed the next steps:

At `FCMPlugin.gradle` I have commented the following line:

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

then edit `ProjectName/plugins/cordova-plugin-fcm/plugin.xml`:

```
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0" />
<framework src="com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0" />
```

This works for me.

Credit: ghosteye on [Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/fcm-and-google-plus-compile-issue/131932/8) (He did an `ionic cordova platform remove android` and then `ionic cordova platform add android@~6.4.0` but it wasn't necessary for me).

Hope it helps.