# Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, build

I have a project and I have the apk, but I have changed a value in the calculate.java file and I want to rebuild the project. But the following error appears. What should I do? I am not an android studio developer and I am only a novice.
"
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3.
Searched in the following locations:

- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.3/gradle-7.0.3.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.0.3/gradle-7.0.3.pom
  Required by:
  project :
  Add google Maven repository and sync project
  Open File
  "

Comment: share gradle build file for root if you can .

Comment: How can I share "gradle file for root"?

Comment: @Azadya Post your build.gradle file

Comment: @JustInCoding  Would u please help me to solve the problem,the followinf file is the build.gradle file.

Comment: I still cannot view your build file. Paste it using Pastebin or something

Comment: @JustInCoding-The file is too log and it can not pasteed here...What is pastebin sir?

Comment: @JustInCoding-----plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.multidev.converter"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

Comment: }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}

Comment: @JustInCoding---I have added in two file. in the top.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure that your build.gradle file contains Google's Maven repository:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url 'https://maven.google.com/'
      name 'Google'
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
      url 'https://maven.google.com/'
      name 'Google'
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Many ```build.gradle``` files have a shortcut to this code block, see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467561/difference-between-google-and-maven-url-https-maven-google-com

Answer (score -2):

Just Add **mavenCentral()** to build.gradle

Comment: You should give some context to this answer. Why/to what extend does this solve OPs problem? Maybe give an example code of the resulting build.gradle file, and preferably a link to additional info