# Gradle 4.1 issue on latest android studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, gradle

Though I have an updated android studio I am getting the following error but I cannot find gradle 4.1 in the gradle folder but when I check file -> project structure -> gradle plugin is 4.

```
Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.pom
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1/gradle-4.1.jar
```

And my build.gradle file is this. I set it to 23 because I need to run it on 5.0.1 phone.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.threewire.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can add this statement to your gradle.properties file

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: I added that as your suggested but still I am getting the same error.

Comment: make sure that the gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties file is 4.1

Comment: like this  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip

Comment: My make project works fine but I am getting the following error.Earlier I was able to over come this error by changing few numbers in gradle settings but now I am unable to. What shall I do?Some one please help me as this is the only thing standing between my and my APK Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.

Cause:
'code' 'The version of Gradle you are using (3.3) does not support the forTasks() method on BuildActionExecuter. Support for this is available in Gradle 3.5 and all later versions.'

Comment: I now set it to 4.1 and it is now making the project but when I tried to build the APK I got the following error                                            Error:Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDevRelease'.
> Keystore file C:\.android\debug.keystore not found for signing config 'release'.

Comment: Worked now. After I set the keystore name, path and passwordand alias

Comment: Now it'll not work, Android Studio shows WARNING: The following project options are deprecated and have been removed: 
android.enableAapt2
This property has no effect, AAPT2 is now always used.
Affected Modules: app, library

Answer (score 137):

check your tools version, it should be 3.0.1

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

please note that `google()` repository is important. the newer plugin is posted there.

Comment: Same, I was missing `google()` and adding it resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This helped me out too, with a project that would build inside Android Studio but not from the command line.

Comment: @threewire can you please change this as the correct answer.

Comment: Adding this just caused another error: Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\mmo\StudioProjects\ListPro\build.gradle' line: 4
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ListPro'.
> Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

Comment: Workaround to last error described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google

Answer (score 34):

Try adding `google()` in repositories.

Answer (score 11):

For my project is correct next construction in "build.gradle":

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Comment: I wanted to post  the same, because this solved the problem for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the android version you are using with standard settings.
use stable version instead for your computer