# Android Studio 3.1.4 Gradle Sync Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, timeout, jcenter

Whenever I create a new project in Android Studio it fails at Gradle Sync and always the same error:

```
Connection timed out: connect

org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom'.
```

A screenshot of the `IDE`: 
[image]

It fails exactly when `GET` this link: `https://jcenter.binary.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.4/gradle-3.1.4.pom`, but it can receive other links like dl.google.com and SDK Manager.
I was getting this error even on `AS 3.1.3` and I haven't ever been able to create an `Android Application` by `Android Studio`. It can be done easily by `Eclipse ADT`, but I wanna use `Android Studio` because it's the official `IDE` for `Android` and Google is supporting `Android Studio`.

Any way to solve this boring failure of `Gradle`?
(I already searched one thousand times at `Google` and `Stack overflow`)

Comment: try setting http proxy in Android studio and use vpn

Comment: I tried that already. Please note that I said: "but it can receive other links like dl.google.com and SDK Manager".

Comment: @هادیفرید Check my answer, you'll sometimes need to Invalidate Caches and reopening Android Studio.

Comment: What does exactly `PLEASE DON'T EDIT MY POST :)` means btw?

Comment: What is your Gradle distribution url?

Comment: Can post your `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Finally it worked!*

### UPDATE (Best Answer)

`JCenter` detects most VPNs, I have a better solution for you (Iranian developers):

*There is a service that helps us to pass restrictions (like `JCenter`, `Android Developer`, and so many services): https://shecan.ir (شکن), you can use that fast service without disconnection or other headaches (it uses `DNS` to bypass restrictions, so usually faster than VPN).*

### Old Answer

Dear Iranian Developers, you can easily solve this problem with these simple steps:

1 - Turn on the `Psiphon`

2 - In the `Psiphon` (VPN) go to Settings -> Local Proxy Ports -> HTTP, HTTPS: `63620` - SOCKS: `63621`. This will force the `Psiphon` to always use port `63620` for HTTP.

3- Go to `AS` Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy -> Manual proxy configuration -> HTTP: Host name: `127.0.0.1` - Port: `63620` -> Uncheck `Proxy Authentication`.

Note: These ports (`63620`, `63621`) are custom, but the HTTP port of the `Psiphon` and the `AS` HTTP Proxy Settings must be the same.

4 - Note: **`Android Studio` works online only the first time you create the project.** After that, you can work offline and build your project or sync it again with `Gradle`.

Done!

Comment: Not working. Also, I am not sure that it's safe to use Iranian dns servers =(

Answer (score 3):

Of course, link ***is blocked*** by our (Iranian IPs) so, the idea is to enable VPN then reopening Android Studio and if it couldn't download it again, Invalidate Caches/Restart :

(`Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart`)

then you should be good to go.

This also could happen for adding a Library in `Gradle.build` which can be bypassed by this method.

Comment: I already enabled VPN and HTTP Proxy and it can connect to developer.android.com... My problem is jcenter.

Comment: Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart. No Changes :(

Comment: This also happens when a VPN have a problem or don't know, can't get connected to that server. Maybe OpenVPN can help.

Comment: Master, my VPN works perfectly and Android Studio can connect to Servers which is restricted our country.

Comment: I have tried the Invalidate Caches but with the same error. And I'm not using any proxies as I'm connecting directly to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue after updating Android Studio.

I resolved it by downgrading the version of **`com.android.tools.build:gradle`** in project level build.gradle file same like old projet.

**1> Open your another project**

-------Check version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle` in Project level gradle

-------Check `distributionUrl` version in **`gradle-wrapper.properties`**

**2> Apply both these version in your project**

**Project level `build.gradle`**

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1' // your version
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip // your version
```

**Sync and run, All errors gone!**

Answer (score 1):

go to address
https://github.com/clarketm/proxy-list
select one proxy and port

Go to AS Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> HTTP Proxy -> Manual proxy configuration -> HTTP: Host name: ip - Port: port ->check Proxy Authentication
 check adress https://developer.android.com/studio/ if ok 
end

Answer (score 1):

use Hotspot Shield

I faced the same problem because this service is banned in Syria

Comment: This should go as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and update the gradle version to the last one:

Old

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
```

New

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

And it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need to add the **google()**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}
```