# Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I was trying to add firebase auth to my android project but getting this error.
I have tried adding 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3' too but its taking more than 40 mins and still not syncing the gradle.

This is build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myaid.startup"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

This is app.gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyAid'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2.
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom'.
>   >     Connection reset
>   >     Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2.
>   >     Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom'.
>   >     Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom'.
>   >     Connection reset
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> CONFIGURE FAILED in 2m 13s ERROR: Connection reset

Comment: network issue, please check your network

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569).

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Please use [android] or other relevant tags instead. Also, you need to create a [mcve] - and do not add screenshots of code

Comment: @Basi I have set -the HTTP Proxy as no proxy and my rest of the things are working, I'm posting this question on the same network. Can you please suggest me something else because I don't think its the network problem.

Comment: @AbhinayShrivastav please remove the images and paste both gradle

Comment: @Basi done the editing, please help.

Comment: @AbhinayShrivastav try to restart android studio

Comment: @Basi I have tried uninstalling it and installed it again still getting this error. Do you think this is something version related problem?

Comment: Please check are you using offline work?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I have uninstalled the android studio 3.3.2 and installed 3.1.0, and now getting " Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom 1m 1s 39ms " AND " Download https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.1.2/gradle-3.1.2.pom 1m 0s 755ms " as new error.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed After going to the links some gradle-3.1.2.pom is downloaded but I don't know where to add it? Can you look into this link and help me if you understand anything. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51797446/android-studio-3-1-4-gradle-sync-failed  I am from INDIA.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450020/4649110) then resync

Comment: @AbhinayShrivastav which version of gradle wrapper you have currently used. For checking this check gradle-wrapper.properties file.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed with 3.3.0 I'm using 4.10 and with 3.1.0 i'm using 4.4

Comment: For 3.3.0 use wrapper version 4.10.1 instead of 4.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by removing all my .gradle files, SDK files, .m2 files, .androidstudio files and then re-installing it.

Followed this answer: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your gradle's proxy settings. Enable it or disable it in the following file:

```
~/.gradle/gradle.properties
```

Like:

```
systemProp.https.proxyPort=1080
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=1080
```

Advices:

1. If your connection to repositories is not stable, use a proxy
   instead of direct connection.
2. If you used to use a proxy for
   gradle, check if it is still working.

Comment: I'm not sure why the settings in my `gradle.properties` file are different from those in Android Studio preferences. Can I safely remove the file so that I connects directly?

Comment: @rraallvv sure, you can remove the proxy settings. Those are unnecessary settings in normal condition.