# org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException:A problem occurred configuring root project after updated to AndroidStudio - 3.5.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Updated Android Studio(3.5.3) not building Android Project, before it was building.
I have checked with Proxy settings still it is getting same
Below are the exceptions after rebuilding the Android Project.

```
  org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Gsa2_NewMenu'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.access$300(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor$1.create(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.ProducerGuard$AdaptiveProducerGuard.guardByKey(ProducerGuard.java:97)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.getResource(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:82)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadByCoords(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.downloadStaticResource(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.parseMetaDataFromArtifact(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.metadata.AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.create(AbstractRepositoryMetadataSource.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver.resolveStaticDependency(ExternalResourceResolver.java:199)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.MavenResolver.doResolveComponentMetaData(MavenResolver.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver$RemoteRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ExternalResourceResolver.java:400)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$ResolveAndCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:381)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:136)
    ... 133 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.2/gradle-3.3.2.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRawGet(HttpClientHelper.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performGet(HttpClientHelper.java:84)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor.openResource(HttpResourceAccessor.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultExternalResourceConnector.openResource(DefaultExternalResourceConnector.java:56)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.openResource(ProgressLoggingExternalResourceAccessor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.AccessorBackedExternalResource.withContentIfPresent(AccessorBackedExternalResource.java:130)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator$11.call(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:350)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:340)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:120)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.withContentIfPresent(BuildOperationFiringExternalResourceDecorator.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.copyToCache(DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor.java:199)
    ... 148 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
```

Below is the app gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XX.XX.XXX"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 13
        versionName "6.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

repositories{
    maven { url "jitpack.io" }
    maven { name 'glide-snapshot'; url 'oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    /*implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })*/
    implementation files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpclient.jar')
    implementation files('libs/apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar')

    implementation files('libs/commons-codec-1.11.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.5.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.8.4'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.3.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'


    implementation(name:'merchantsdk', ext:'aar')
    implementation(name:'ezetapandroidsdk', ext:'aar')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/org.apache.commons.io.jar')
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Below is the Project build gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have checked online, but none worked.I am stuck from 4 days, Please check my App and Project gradle files and let me know.Please help me on this.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does it build on command line? It's only a socket timeout trying to access the google maven repository. It seems more related to your system and environment than to your build.

Comment: in your Gradle file you add `gson` library implementation two times

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing sequence from:

**FROM:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
```

**TO:**

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
                google()
                jcenter()
           maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
        mavenCentral()


        }
```

Then **ReSync** Project

Comment: Hi Sagar, I have tried but still the same exception exists.

Comment: Can you remove proxy from gradle.properties?

Comment: Proxy is not there in gradle.properties.It contains these statemets - org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m, android.useAndroidX=true, android.enableJetifier=true

Comment: can you comment out android.useAndroidX=true, android.enableJetifier=true
as i can see there is no kotlin used in code.

Then resync

Comment: Yes, still the same.May you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

That is most likely a wrong network configuration.

This answer might help you: [Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240175/could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-3-2)

If none of this works try to reinstall Android Studio: [How to completely uninstall Android Studio from windows(v10)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39953495/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-from-windowsv10)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use this link and  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2' used

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks messed up. New projects created using **Android Studio 3.0** and higher also includes Google's Maven repository by using `google()`. There's no point of using,

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    name 'Google'
}
```

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build) your top-level **build.gradle** file should look like this,

```
 buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        }
    }  

    allprojects {
       repositories {
           google()
           jcenter()
           maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io'
          }
       }
    }

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also, you are using an old version of gradle wrapper. I suggest you change the **gradle-wrapper.properties** with the following configuration:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```