# Android studio 3.2.1 ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

After I update Android Studio to 3.2.1 and gradle version in my project I am getting following build error.

I have already checked lots of questions related this question but no luck.

**Project dependency Build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        gradlePluginPortal()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter ()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Error**

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring root project 'DemoAppppp'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:944)

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
Required by:
    project :
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:63)

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveComponentMetaData(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:139)

Caused by: org.gradle.api.resources.ResourceException: Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.failure(ResourceExceptions.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.ResourceExceptions.getFailed(ResourceExceptions.java:57)

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpRequestException: Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.2.1/gradle-3.2.1.pom'.
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper.performRequest(HttpClientHelper.java:96)

Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:80 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect 
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

**Update**

I just followed @CoolMind answer it solve the gradle issue, but there is another issue comes which is [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218535/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv)

And I followed those answers which is given in this question but not solve my problem

Comment: check your connectivity while building gradle for project, also make sure you are not behind any firewall.

Comment: Yes, I already checked my firewall

Comment: Clean project from Build -> clean project

Comment: @ElmiraFrhn Every time

Comment: if you're in a sanctioned country use vpn/proxy that covers the whole PC restart Android Studio and make sure google() is first option and mavenCentral() is second

Answer (score 130, accepted):

**Just turn off the Toggle Offline Mode** .

On the top right side of the Window .

> Click on Gradle
> 2nd number option(just near of Setting option)
> click on it then you will be able to do work continuously.

**As you can see the image**

[image]

Comment: thanks.i faced this issue due to internet connectivity and gradle went offline mode. now after changing it back to onlilne its working fine

Comment: It is hard to tell whether you are in 'offline' or not offline mode.  I think having the little interrupted horizontal bar means offline.  Having a gray box around the bar means not-offline -- ie online.  Having the tool tip just say toggle offline doesn't help.  Seeing it in a dark theme is hard too.

Comment: Doesn't work! The Twitter SDK is giving this error

Comment: Thanks a million, this just resolved it, never knew my offline mode was turned on

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Toggling offline mode makes no difference whatsoever. I think you should take out the 100% solution part!

Comment: @gignu then  may be you have different problem

Comment: @Vikassingh no, I get exactly the same error message as in the title of this question. The solution in my case was to upgrade my FLIPPER_VERSION in my gradle.properties file which was outdated. Once I did that, the error was gone and the build succeeded. If you're interested and want to reproduce it, change your FLIPPER_VERSION to 0.52.1 and you should get the same build error as in the title of this question.

Answer (score 37):

In my case, I have added a dependency which is not available in any of the cloud repositpories. On **removing dependency**,it started working

Comment: for me okhttp dependency was wrong

Comment: For me androidx.camera:camera-mlkit-vision:1.2.1. Maybe I've written the wrong version number. But I suppose this was in some ML Kit part of the docs.

Comment: This was my problem it was the dependence that i had initially added

Answer (score 33):

In The Right Side of the Android Studio, You can See Gradle option just click it and you will see a screen which is given below.

Gradle can be offline. If offline, you should do it online.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is what solved my issue. they just removed the option from settings ‍♂️

Answer (score 15):

You might have added a dependency not available in the repository

Comment: This. The real issue was one step above in the error tree, not the error from the title of this post.

Answer (score 7):

**Check the below points.**

1. Internet connectivity issue.
2. Toggle Offline Mode.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My problem was because a version was wrong in the dependencies in build.gradle (app). If you have internet, it might be because of this, so try finding other warnings that might indicate a wrong dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem also. Tried all the suggestions, but didnt help. The problem was in offline/online mode as other stated but you have to also check the compiler settings. Make sure there is no **--offline** flag

Preferences -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler

( Menubar 'File' button, 'Settings' menu option, 'Build, Execution, Deployment' menu twisty, 'Compiler' submenu )

On Command-line Options: --stacktrace

not

--offline --stacktrace

Answer (score 2):

Opening the "Gradle" side panel, and toggling the "online/offline" button to "online" worked for me as well.

Previous failed solution: I searched on Gradle's website for a manual download of version 3.6.3, but there wasn't one. That number is the same version, however, of Android Studio being used.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, there is always a dependency that you might have added that doesn't exit, so you have to find and delete it.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This problem appeared on OS X. After disabling web filtering application (some Google IPs were blocked) it disappeared. After syncing with gradle all files have been downloaded.

Also you may set a checkbox like in https://discuss.gradle.org/t/android-studio-could-not-get-resource-https-dl-google-com-dl-android-maven2-com-android-tools-build-gradle-3-1-0-gradle-3-1-0-pom/26734:

Settings -> Build … -> Gradle -> Android Studio -> Enable embedded maven repository.

See also [Could not resolve com.android.tools.build.gradle:3.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276868/could-not-resolve-com-android-tools-build-gradle3-0-1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solves the gradle issue, but there is one more problem occurs which is  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218535/unable-to-resolve-dependency-for-appdebug-compileclasspath-could-not-resolv).

Comment: and I just follows those answers which is given in that question but no luck

Comment: @vikassingh, sorry, but I don't know, how to help in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If you have updated Gradle then most likely you will get this error because Gradle will be offline by default after updating.

Solution:

In right hand side top corner click Gradle (Gradle panel or Gradle window opens). 
Connect Gradle to the internet by clicking the icon at the top of Gradle panel or window.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when your android studio is not getting internet connection. You fix the internet, the problem fixes by itself.
To confirm the internet issue of the android studio you can attempt to login, update, connecting to firebase, etc all will fail.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the issue was organization's Artifactory password got changed needed to update Gradle with new credentials.

Answer (score 1):

upgrade project to androidx
change compile to implementation
change v4 or v7 to androidx dependencies

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to turn on the Toggle button, come in the grade menu at the right side of the window... So you going to online mode.. you must have internet connection for.. build grade.. otherwise it's again show you same error or other types of error...

Answer (score 0):

I also have been having the same error since when i updated my Android studio and even with a fast internet network am unable to start a new project but today I discover a solution just click o your event log and update any suggested plugin that shows up and rebuild your project, then your have your project working well and fine it worked for me trust it to work for you also .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone's else problem ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

This Works 100%

**turn off the Toggle Offline Mode .**

Check the image below

[image]

Comment: lolz. Love your confidence but it doesn't work :D

Comment: I don't know why it doesn't worked for you But it worked well for me

Comment: This is redundant. Your answer is simply repeating what others have said.

Answer (score 0):

This error may arrises due to "android:exported="false"". please make sure when to use "android:exported="true/false"".

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the above helped. I had to upgrade my FLIPPER_VERSION in my `gradle.properties` file. You can find the latest FLIPPER_VERSION here: https://github.com/facebook/flipper/releases

Answer (score 0):

Deleting my .gradle file ("C:\Users<userName>.gradle") and going to the device manager and running "Cold Boot Now" fixed this problem for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to **Toggle Offline Mode**, if not worked check your flipper version if it is old try to update it(worked for me). Upgrading flipper version in ***gradle.properties***

From

```
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.39.0
```

To

```
FLIPPER_VERSION=0.99.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I added maven repository in both repository section , so this issue occurs, So I removed this line from above repotories section inside buildscript
for reference visit this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75005827/12748481

Answer (score 0):

i faced this issue after adding

```
implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.1.0")
```

i removed it and issue resolved.

moral of the story:
**remove older implementations** if (another resource already has newer classes)
also check internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

In my case to make it work I removed the .gradle and .idea folders and then make an invalidate & restart. I hope I can help someone!