# React native android can not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Any people met the issue Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':react-native-fast-image:classpath' and can not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3 ? I try open the project structure and see the gradle plugin tool is 3.6.3 and the gradle version is 5.4.6 but i dont know what happen now

The build.gradle file :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    /*ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }*/
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                def requested = details.requested
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms') {
                    details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
                if (requested.group == 'com.google.firebase') {
                    details.useVersion '12.0.1'
                }
            }
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "27.1.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 28
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "15.0.1"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
}
project.ext {
    excludeAppGlideModule = true
}

/*
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.7'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

I added `google()` to `build.gradle` to resolve the problem:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem... just that mine was not about 'react-native-fast-image:classpath'. Mine was
Caused by:

> org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

I added "google()" in the build.gradle file and it worked form me.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had one issue also with not finding com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3, but not using React, in my case it worked. [Check here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932195/android-studio-3-2-1-artifactresolveexception-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-f)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it's react native fast image use the different version with my tool version ...

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue and would try to test if your solution works with me too, but any better info on how to fix this: "react native fast image use the different version with my tool version" :)

Cheers

Comment: i check inside bundle.gradle of android studio is different build tool version with the react native fast image from node_modules ...