# Android Studio:Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I created a new project in Android Studio and an error pops up:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'About Me'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.0-release-764.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.5.0-release-764/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.5.0-release-764.pom
     Required by:
         project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400029/cant-new-project-kotlin-after-update-android-studio-4-2 probably duplicated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.0"
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

it looks like there is some problems in server side just change kotlin version to 1.5.0 instead of 1.5.0-release-764

Answer (score 0):

try this one :-

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
```

hope this will your answer visit this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75005827/12748481

Answer (score -3):

I just closed the project and restarted it, error gone