# Gradle build error: Could not find semver4j-0.16.4-nodeps.jar

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

I recently started seeing a build error in our CircleCI build:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find semver4j-0.16.4-nodeps.jar (com.github.gundy:semver4j:0.16.4).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jitpack.io/com/github/gundy/semver4j/0.16.4/semver4j-0.16.4-nodeps.jar
```

Re-running the job sometimes allows the build to complete, even though when I locally attempt to load that URL (https://jitpack.io/com/github/gundy/semver4j/0.16.4/semver4j-0.16.4-nodeps.jar), I get an error: "Not found in JitPack repository".

I tried running the build locally with the `--refresh-dependencies` gradle option, and I was able to reproduce the error... but only once. With no changes to my build.gradle file, the build succeeded the next time I tried it.

I found that the Kotlin gradle plugin's dependency on semver4j was modified in [this commit](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/b6edf9a86eaf00096b41dd1a69fb78e1af9b03b5), making it an [embedded dependency](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/commit/b6edf9a86eaf00096b41dd1a69fb78e1af9b03b5#diff-88364dae0accb9d5b244d427ce9df7c6d33e60a7480e93f8f79393d7d402c18eR87). I was hopeful that upgrading the Kotlin gradle plugin to 1.7.0 would pick up this change, but I'm not sure that it did; it certainly didn't fix my CircleCI build issues.

I did confirm that jitpack is included in the repositories section of our build.gradle file:

```
maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

I'm hoping someone else has a fix for this, or some gradle magic that can serve as a workaround?

Comment: I think you your issue inside build.gradle file, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75005827/12748481

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `buildscript`:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      //maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' } // Delete
      // Add:
      maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.gundy/semver4j' }
   }
}
```

In `allprojects`, add it but over the *jitpack* one:

```
maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.gundy/semver4j'}
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
```

Comment: This makes sense. Having a URL to the mvnrepository.com repo was the key. So far, this change is working well for me, as expected. And I noticed this is one of your first contributions to Stack Overflow... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like some Jitpack's services are suffering an outage, check it out on https://status.jitpack.io/

Comment: Good to know — thanks for the link! I've tweeted asking if they have any news on what's going on. It would be nice if this were more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

for: study/firebase-android-sdk/buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

```
repositories {
    maven(url = "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.gundy/semver4j")
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven(url = "https://maven.google.com/")
    maven(url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/android-ci/mvn/")
    maven(url = "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
}
```

Key point:
Add `mavenCentral()` could work, if not, add
`https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.gundy/semver4j` too.