# Installing gradle offline in Android Studio-3.6.2

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, gradle

When I install Gradle offline it shows me this error message:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$Artifact Resolve Exception: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':class path'.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio 3.2.1 ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932195/android-studio-3-2-1-artifactresolveexception-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-f)

Answer (score 0):

**Just turn off the Toggle Offline Mode**

[image]

for more refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55605945/12830957)

Comment: when I  turn off the Toggle Offline Mode
show me these two message

org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2.

Comment: do u have a great internet connection