# Problem occurred configuring project ':app'

Tags: android, kotlin

Problem occurred when updating android plugin and Gradle to 7.0.2 and SDK Version and sdkBuildTools to 31. Running on Mac Apple M1 processor.

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/29.0-jre/guava-29.0-jre.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:2.2.0
> Could not find com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.30.9.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/1.30.9/google-api-client-1.30.9.pom
> If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:2.2.0

Possible solution:
Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio 3.2.1 ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932195/android-studio-3-2-1-artifactresolveexception-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-f)