# artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio

I have working an application without problem in Android Studio 3.2.1 After a long time of absence, I just downloaded Androoid Studio 2021.1 and when I try to run my appli_cation I get this error.

[image]

I tried this solution [lien](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932195/android-studio-3-2-1-artifactresolveexception-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-f#:%7E:text=Solution%20%C3%A0%20100,voir%20sur%20l%27image) but it didn't change anything

I've been looking for a solution for 2 days now. I have already tried all the solutions proposed on StackOverflow and other site but the problem remains the same.

According to the log all my libraries seem to have problems and I don't know why.

Here are my build.gradle files

Project:

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    //jcenter()
    maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    //jcenter()
    maven {url 'https://jitpack.io'}
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 31
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "cm.logram.lecitoyen"
    minSdkVersion 16
    versionCode 8
    versionName "1.1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    resConfigs "fr"
    multiDexEnabled true

  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
       // minifyEnabled true
        //shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
       // minifyEnabled true
        //shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
    }
   }

  dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  //noinspection GradleCompatible
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
  implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:20.1.2'

  implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.6'
  implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:simplealertdialog:1.2.1@aar'
  implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-alpha01'
  implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0-alpha02'
  implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
  //implementation 'com.chootdev:recycleclick:1.0.0'

  implementation 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
  implementation 'com.xeoh.android:text-highlighter:1.0.3'
  implementation 'com.androidadvance:topsnackbar:1.1.1'
  implementation 'com.crowdfire.cfalertdialog:cfalertdialog:1.1.0'
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9'
  implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

  implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.4@aar'
  implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.2@aar'
  implementation 'com.github.smarteist:autoimageslider:1.3.2-appcompat'

  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.10.0'
  implementation 'com.cjj.persei:library:1.0.0'
  implementation 'com.vatsal.imagezoomer:image-zoomer:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.9.1'
  implementation 'io.github.kobakei:ratethisapp:1.2.0'
  implementation 'com.github.ivbaranov:materiallettericon:0.2.3'

  implementation 'com.github.hsmnzaydn:imagezoom:1.2.1'
  implementation 'com.github.devendroid:ReadMoreOption:1.0.2'

  //Ads
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.6.0'


  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha06'
  implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

  }
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```