# When I open my emulator in my Android Studio then the build output pop up and showing continuously this problem

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

Comment: Update : Finally solve this problem. I was using a dependency which was not found by gradle internet [implementation : 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1]. After remove that dependency my code run successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As response in:
[Android studio 3.2.1 ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53932195/android-studio-3-2-1-artifactresolveexception-could-not-resolve-all-artifacts-f)

Check if the build gradle is in offline mode

Comment: Already checked it. It is in online.  But still showing this error

Answer (score 0):

Update : Finally solve this problem. I was using a dependency which was not found by gradle internet [implementation : 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1]. After remove that dependency,synchronize it and  my code run successfully.