# Could not find method google() error in victory charts in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, victory-charts

I'm totally new to React Native and victory native charts. I want to add victory native chart for my projects. So I followed all the steps from here
https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native/blob/master/README.md

When I'm building the project I'm getting this error

```
Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository
```

please don't mark this as duplicate, because I already tried all solutions for above probilem. I tried this as well

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
    }
}
```

But still I'm getting the error. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Is you tried `react-native link` ?

Comment: yes.nothing happens

Comment: May I ask why you are using `google()` ? I used `victory-charts`, there is nothing about `google()`.

Comment: When I'm building the project I'm getting that error. After tht I searched a solution for that. That is the reason I added google() there. Please read the question again :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to upgrade Gradle to version 4.x (and as it seems [also Android Studio etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google)), because your version does not support this syntax.

If you don't want to upgrade, use

```
maven {
    url 'https://maven.google.com'
}
```

which does the same as the `google()` shortcut.

(If it is still not working, please post your used versions of Gradle and Android Studio.)