# CI server error: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm aware that this error can be caused by using old versions of Gradle and the Android Gradle plugin, but in this case this build error only occurs on the remote cloud-based CI server (Nevercode) and not locally (either in Android Studio, or command line). The project is using recent versions of both. This appears to be a different cause to that mentioned in other questions about this error.

gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip
```

root build.gradle:

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()  // <-- Error points to (line 7) here
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
}
```

Build error:

```
Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
/build.gradle' line: 7
```

Gradle cannot find the definition of google() but this should work with Gradle 4.0+ and Android Gradle plugin v3.0+ according to this [Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google)

Switching google() to maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } does not fix the issue.

I have other projects that build just fine with this CI provider, using what appear to be the same configurations. The project with the issue is being built by the CI server in a fresh virtual machine, from the repository source, so I would not expect any cached state issues to cause this. It is intriguing that it builds ok locally every time, just not on the CI server.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this was that in the "app" module of the project (one level below the project root) there was a second copy of gradle and the gradle wrapper, and the gradle wrapper was configured to an old v2.2.

Locally this is not a problem, but for whatever reason Nevercode CI uses that Gradle v2.2 from the app module for builds, and then fails as the version is way too old.

If you see this scenario, check your sub-modules for stray copies of older versions of Gradle...