# Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'getCompileConfiguration()' when using Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I use `Firebase` at the first time in my application and I follow [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) and when I add this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

It gives me an error like that .

```
Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'getCompileConfiguration()'
```

my `app.build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.webstore.whatsapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

  dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'

}
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

my `project.build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'

}
}

 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
}
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

Comment: post the full code..

Comment: I didn't write any codes yet :D just trying to create the db :D

Comment: yes i know.. i means your `gradle` file

Comment: I edited it in my question

Comment: try my answer. i updated

Comment: @KopiBryant it gives me `Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'`

Comment: @Ahmed did you update the android plugin?Which version are you using?!

Comment: Sorry but can u explain more ? if you mean gradle . I updated it 
`compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"`

Comment: `Gradle DSL method not found: google()` can try referring this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google

Comment: u need to update this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'` as I said, but you don't want to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upgrade:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

to this:

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
```

Also if you are going to use the latest version of firebase then upgrade android studio to 3.1

> If you're not using Android Studio 3.1 to develop your app, you will need to upgrade in order to get the correct version checking behavior within the IDE.
>
> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/announcing-new-sdk-versioning.html

Comment: You mean my problem won't be solved until upgrading my Android studio ?

Answer (score 1):

Try add this 2 line in your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

**2nd Edit**

try this too

```
buildscript {
repositories {
jcenter()
google()
}
dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.1'

}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
jcenter()
google()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and You can upgrade your gradle version to 27

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27

defaultConfig {
applicationId "com.webstore.whatsapp"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 27
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
release {
    minifyEnabled false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: and try replace this line `maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }` to `google()`

Comment: When I add `google()` a selection menu appears to choose the plugin .. what plugin should I choose?

Answer (score 1):

You can add firebase from the android studio on following steps,

If you're using Android Studio version 2.2 or later, the Firebase Assistant is the simplest way to connect your app to Firebase. The Assistant can connect your existing project or create a new one for you with all the necessary Gradle dependencies.

If you're using an older version of Android Studio or have a more complex project configuration, you can still manually add Firebase to your app.

Use the Firebase Assistant
To open the Firebase Assistant in Android Studio:

Click Tools > Firebase to open the Assistant window.
Click to expand one of the listed features (for example, Analytics), then click the provided tutorial link (for example, Log an Analytics event).
Click the Connect to Firebase button to connect to Firebase and add the necessary code to your app.

So you can easily add firebase and its service to your project and link all in a quick way.

Happy coding...

You can find details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)

Comment: I mentioned the doc in my question . And my Android studio version is less than 2.2 and in my question too I mentioned that I add the Firebase manually then I have this error

Comment: Try this link ?.

https://medium.com/@pmarcus93/solving-the-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-in-android-studio-6e5ab499bd3

Comment: I think this isn't my problem