# how to solve the gradle error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

hello Im realy need some help to my project gradle... 
Im new in android studio and now I have problem with gradle.
hlep me please...

Its my gradle code (Project:)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        apply plugin: 'java'
        apply plugin: 'announce'
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.shoaib.newsletters"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.tomerrosenfeld.customanalogclockview:custom-analog-clock-view:1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

and now my messages gradle Sync is

```
Error:(7, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'NewsLetters' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

now Im using Gradle 3.2.1 in local
Please help me :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google)

Answer (score 0):

Use gradle `3.1.2`, not `3.2.1`, unless you absolutely have to have `3.2.1`.

When I tried to build with gradle 3.2.1, it failed, saying this:

> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a version of Gradle lower than 4.1. Change the distribution URL in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` as follows:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.8-all.zip`

To locate the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file, press `ctrl + shift + N` in Android Studio and type `gradle-wrapper`

Change the dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently Android studio 3.2 is not in stable state. Its in canary release state.
So its gradle plugin is in alpha state

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha17'
```

This version of gradle plugin is available in Android Studio 3.2 Canary17

If you want to use stable version then download Android Studio 3.1.3

Comment: I've downloaded Android Studio 3.2.1 and this is still broken. Still get the error in I. Renk's comment