# Android Studio not working. Sync failed download services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

Tags: android, android-studio

Ive recently formated my computer and tried to install Android Studio to continue my work.
However its not working properly. First it showed lots of erros on the wizard that could not download the SDKs. I download them manually and now i can open the IDE.
However now it just do not sync with a new app (just as example) like shown on this picture.
[image]

I dont even see Android option on Tool menu.
Anybody got a clue?

Comment: Are you using any proxy?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52566323/6401241

Comment: well i dont know why but it worked now... i didnt change anything... does it do any process on the background because suddely it asked to download missing tools and it did work... anyway thanks for attention and i hope some other people find this "automatic" solution too