# Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, appcompatactivity

Although this question has been asked before, none of the solutions are working for me.

The problem is that suddenly out of nowhere `Android Studio` started throwing the error that `Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity`. On clicking Alt+Enter on my Windows, it shows me

```
Add library 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2' to classpath
```

as one of the options.

Even though I have the following dependency in my gradle which always worked till today

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

So far I have tried

1. Cleaning project
2. Invalidating caches and restarting
3. Deleting libraries folder from .idea folder and restarting studio
4. Closing and reopening the project
5. Removing the dependency from gradle, syncing with gradle and adding dependency again

None of these solutions work and I am not able to understand what the issue is. This already ended up wasting lots of development time. Can someone please help. Thanks!

Edit: Adding dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':ratemyapp')
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.18'

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation files('libs/gcm.jar')

    // Facebook SDK Core only (Analytics)
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-core:4.33.0'

    // Facebook Login only
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.33.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.14.2'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'

    /**
     * Google
     */
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:strict-version-matcher-plugin:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.2'

    //compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.2.1.jar')
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    // CardView
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.pixplicity.multiviewpager:library:1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.4.1@aar'
    implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5.2'
    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:percent:27.1.1'


    /*For Request Server*/
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.1.6.0'

    /**
     * Animation.
     */
    implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
    implementation 'net.soulwolf.widget:ratiolayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'

    /**
     * Event Bus.
     */
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.wefika:flowlayout:0.4.1'

    /**
     * Ring capcha
     */
    implementation 'com.thrivecom:ringcaptcha:1.0.11@aar'

    /**
     * Zendesk
     */
    implementation 'com.zopim.android:sdk:1.3.7.1'
    implementation 'com.zendesk:support:2.0.0'
    implementation('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation('io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.12@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.5.9'

    implementation 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:5.+'
    implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.11'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.11'

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    // Room
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

    // Paging
    implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.0'

    // Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation 'android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1'

    // Test helpers for Room
    testImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.6'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.rubensousa:gravitysnaphelper:1.5'
    implementation 'me.everything:overscroll-decor-android:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:recyclerview-integration:4.4.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.zcweng:switch-button:0.0.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.shuhart.bubblepagerindicator:bubblepagerindicator:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.iarcuschin:simpleratingbar:0.1.5'
    implementation 'co.omise:omise-android:2.6.4'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
    implementation 'com.adjust.sdk:adjust-android:4.13.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
    implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.19'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.19'
    implementation 'net.cachapa.expandablelayout:expandablelayout:2.9.2'
    implementation project(':menu')
    implementation project(':base')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:16.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

    implementation 'com.google.android.instantapps:instantapps:1.1.0'

    implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.4'
    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'

    //OTP
    implementation 'com.poovam:pin-edittext-field:1.1.2'

    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.1'

}
```

Edit: Top level gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    zendeskSdkVersion = "2.0.0"
    appCompatVersion = "27.0.2"
}

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Log when trying to build project

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':MyModule:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:16)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithKotlincTask.compile(KaptWithKotlincTask.kt:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:788)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:755)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: show all your gradle file

Comment: Is this thing happening for All of `AppCompat` classes? Or just for `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: @MahdiKhansari I just tried AppCompatTextView and it worked.:/

Comment: @MaksimNovikov Its is 500 lines long, do you want me to post any specific portion?

Comment: hmm, i think the `dependencies {...}` will be enough, i think maybe you have conflicts.

Comment: @MaksimNovikov done

Comment: please share your other gradle file

Comment: @Radesh which gradle file?

Comment: module gradle file

Comment: @Radesh This is the gradle file of the module I am using. Do you want the top level gradle file?

Comment: also did you try to build and see build log ? if so send that log too

Comment: are you using intellji on your machince beside android studio @varunkr

Comment: yes, top level.

Comment: @Rajesh added both

Comment: @RamzyHassan Hmm, I'm not sure what you mean by using Intellji besides atudio. I only use Android Studio on my machine

Comment: did you have tasksUtils.kt ?

Comment: @Radesh I tried to search for it and seems like it is not there

Comment: interesting, add your module apply plugin

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187554/discussion-between-varunkr-and-radesh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the help however I had to uninstall and reinstall `Android Studio` and only then the errors went away.

Answer (score 1):

First check this answer [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52566323/6401241)

Second update your versions change all 27.1.1 to 28.0.0  also change

```
compileSdkVersion = 28
targetSdkVersion = 28
```

some wrongs in your code :

**1)** you have 2 cardview in your dependencies

**2)** you don't use this ext

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    zendeskSdkVersion = "2.0.0"
    appCompatVersion = "27.0.2"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd look into the other answer. However I can't change the compile and target sdk versions since we're not allowed to do that. I'd do it if it were my personal project.

Comment: so i thing try to level down gradle version to 3.0.1

Comment: @varunkr did you use this code annotation ViewsById