# ERROR: Could not find method implimentation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on project ':app'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

i have a serious problem when i want to execute old source code!

when i  edit some thing i have error like,

```
"ERROR: Could not find method implimentation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on project ':app'. Open File"
```

Or

when I add `google()` to project `build.gradle` :

```
"ERROR: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
Open File"
```

there is my code:

APP Builde gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'    

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.studioninja.antivirus.mobilesecurity"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implimentation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testimplimentation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implimentation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    implimentation 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    implimentation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'

    implimentation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.2.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.2.1'


    implimentation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.6'
    implimentation 'com.takwolf.android:lock9view:0.0.11'
    implimentation 'org.zakariya.stickyheaders:stickyheaders:0.7.5'
    implimentation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implimentation 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    implimentation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'

    implimentation 'com.liulishuo.magicprogresswidget:library:1.0.9'


    implimentation "com.mikepenz:crossfadedrawerlayout:1.0.0@aar"
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    // used to generate the Open Source section
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries
    compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
        exclude module: "fastadapter"
    }

    // icon fonts used inside the sample
    // https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics
    implimentation 'com.mikepenz:material-design-iconic-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
    implimentation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'


}
```

Project builde gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle.propreties :

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
```

i'am waiting for your help thank u all :)

Comment: Well, Change `implimentation` with `implementation`, hope your problem will be solved.

Comment: i change it and have some other errors

Comment: Update your `build:tools` version with the newest one. I used this below in my current project. Check if it works or not.
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'`

Answer (score 2):

You are using **`implimentation`** instead of **`implementation`**

Also to use the `google()` repo you have to use:

- Gradle plugin for Android 3.x
- Gradle version 4.x

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google/45854844#45854844).

Comment: ah okay wait please i will test it

Comment: now i have this error : ERROR: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
Open File

Comment: @HamzaMoukaliif Just changing `implimentation` to `implementation` in the `dependencies` block of your `build.gradle` file. For the `google()` repo check the updated answer.

Comment: i did it but now i have this error :ERROR: Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.
Open File

Comment: For the `google()` repo check the updated answer. You are using old versions.

Comment: when i update to : dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1' 

 i have this error : ERROR: Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta1] on root project 'source-code'.

Comment: Today you can use classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1', updating also Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

i got  it solution, Where you using

`implimentation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` change this to

`compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: The use of `compile` is obsolete.You have to use `implementation` or `api`

Comment: But this line always includes **`compile`**, not `implementation`. Because it is not a third party library and sorry for my bad english

Comment: The syntax is `implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

Comment: i exchanged **`compile`** to `implementation` and i have coming same **`error`**, because implementation is not allowed in `fileTree`.