# Gradle DSL method not found: 'ooapply()'

Tags: java, android, gradle

I receiving this error after tried solving the google() error following the link [StackOverflow Link] ([Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45781489/error6-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-google))

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The code for gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Mon Jun 19 10:50:31 IST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

My Android studio version is 3.3.2

The following is the full error appeared. Little help would be highly useful.

```
Gradle DSL method not found: 'ooapply()'
Possible causes:
The project 'MyProject' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
Upgrade plugin to version 3.3.2 and sync project

The project 'MyProject' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

I was unable to proceed ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a problem in another **build.gradle** file.
The file you have attached is probably a *Project-level* **build.gradle**.

I guess that the problem is inside *Module-level* **build.gradle** file. Open this file and replace **ooapply** with **apply**.

Comment: Thank you , At the same time I tried building using the latest gradle file provided by Google [Github Project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-media-controller/blob/master/build.gradle). And upgraded to Android Studio 3.5 for the Git Project.